# AWS ECS task go in pending state

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, docker-container

I have create a cluster in aws ecs forgate and than created a task. I noticed that my task always changes its state from `pending` to `running` every 4-5 minutes which causes my application to restart again and again.

I do not want this functionality, can anyone tell how to fix this problem.

Comment: Do you have any logs? Can you run your docker container localy?

Comment: I checked logs in which it is showing my spring boot application started successfully.  I did not try to run docker container locally. I am trying this with aws ecs forgate service

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/using_awslogs.html

Comment: In my experience this means that *something* is killing the container. The usual suspects are:

1) Your code crashed (process exit)

2) Code in a dependent container crashed

3) The load balancer can't reach your health check for some reason, so it kills the container.

Once the container is killed, ECS will try and start another one - hence the PENDING -> RUNNING -> PENDING cycle (which I not so affectionately have nicknamed the death spiral)

Answer (score 0):

same situtation happend to me when i was running containers using fargate , then i checked my metrics, the cpu utilization is more than 90 percent for me so its always failing and after that restarting again... the alocated resources is not sufficient for me.
so while ur creating the task definiton, give cpu and memory high..